# No HTTP response from Chrome extension to my Java Server

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

This is my very first question I am posting on StackOverflow. I usually tend to find answers to any question I have for whatever project, but I am really stuck on this one. I'm writing a Chrome extension that attempts to send JSON-objects over a HTTP post request with certain data in it to a basic Java server that will -in a later stage- process some of the data and return a HTTP response with relevant (processed) information for the client. This is the relevant JavaScript snippet on client-side:

```
function postRequest(jsonObject) {
    var param = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (request.readyState == 4) {
             console.log(request.response);
         }
    };
    request.open("POST", "http://"+link);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain");
    request.send(param);
    // request.abort();
}
```

The input JSON-object is legit and the link-item is the predefined host IP of the server. The server-side code is Java-based and is the following:

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1024);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Request: ");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(line + "\r\n");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Response:");
            String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n" + "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * \r\n"
                    + "Connection: close \r\n" + "\r\n";
            System.out.println(response);
            pw.write(response);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(line + "\r\n");
            }
            br.close();
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Socket Closed");
            System.out.println("");
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do whatever
        }
    }
}}
```

The server does receive the request and the JSON-object, but no response is received on client side (readyState is usually 4, but status code is 0 and responseText is empty). Additionally the connection is not closed when I don't use request.abort() or close the extension's window. It for sure has nothing to do with the permissions in the manifest file, so I didn't include it in this post. Can somebody see what my mistake is or anybody have had a similar experience?

***EDIT:***
The HTTP request is received on server side and looks like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: [IP address of the server; I deleted the exact address for privacy]
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 173
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://nhpingbdjkkljheamibjobneeehiednk
Content-type: text/plain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
```

Since the request is received on server side, I figured that the actual sending of the response is currently unsuccessful. Might it have something to do with the origin domain of the client? When I copy-paste that domain in my browser, I get a ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: `// Do whatever` is that what you actually have in your catch block? or did you omit that part?

Comment: I haven't filled out anything yet in that part of the code.

Comment: you should at least have a `ex.printStackTrace()` there, otherwise you don't know if you are getting an error.

Comment: Fair enough. But that is not really what my question was about.

Comment: Try to make your request with [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It a bit easier to handle.

Comment: Have you looked in the DevTools to see what actually went out/came back? That appears to be the obvious step to determine if the problem is on the client side or the server side.

Comment: @Deliaz: thanks for tip; I will look into that! @

Comment: @Mayken: DevTools doesn't particularly say that anything is wrong with the network traffic and the console stays empty or just prints the status. I did make an edit in my question where I show you the HTTP request that I dod receive on server side (see above). Might it have something to do with the origin domain?

Comment: I also tried it using fetch API now, but the problem remains exactly the same. So I'm starting to think it might really have to with the origin domain of the extension.